# Не могу собрать и запустить qt проект

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Скачал я qt и Qt,и решил поизучать,посмотреть.

Так как c++ не очень хорошо знаю а опыта не очень,то прошу о помощи.
При создании проекта я обратил внимание на *это* в основных сообщениях:

```
Выполняется поиск устройств WinRT.
C:/Qt/Qt5.11.0/5.11.0/winrt_armv7_msvc2015/bin/winrtrunner.exe --list- 
devices
Обнаружено 1 устройство WinRT.
Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'cl'. Output:
===================
===================
Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?
Ошибка разбора файла C:\Users\timax\Documents\Test1\Test1.pro. Отмена.
```

И проект не запускается.

Покопавшись я обнаружил,
что есть 
`Desktop Qt 1.11.0 MSVC2015 32bit` и
`Desktop Qt 1.11.0 MSVC2015 64bit`
и пишет "Ошибка: у комплекта не задан компилятор"
Как это исправить?

Comment: Установить компилятор vc++, то бишь поставить Visual Studio

Comment: Это как? не понимаю.

Comment: visual studio есть и программировал на ней до этого

Comment: `Cannot run compiler 'cl'` говорит о том, что ее нет. Или может у вас версия студии другая?

Comment: Хорошо,что если visual c++ есть,но qt не видит его?

Comment: Найдите в параметрах вкладку комплекты и настройте там пути к компилятору

Comment: У меня visual studio 2017.Еще я очень новичок и могу показаться тупым

Comment: @Apkfile в QtCreator есть меню Инструменты, в нём пункт параметры, в открывшемся окне есть вкладка комплекты, там указаны все доступные вам комплекты, если выделить любой комплект то отобразятся параметры комплекта, в числе которых будет указан компилятор, если он не был найден QtCreator автоматически, то видимо Вам его нужно указать вручную - путь до файла

Comment: >>Еще я очень новичок<< предлагаю вам такую штуку https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheQtCompany.QtVisualStudioTools-19123 Ставите в студию, в студии отмечаете путь к куте, и там же привязываете компиляторы. Далее, работаете как и с другими проектами именно в студии, и через неё же всё компилируете.

Comment: По началу могут быть проблемы (особенно это касается небольших багов когда проект студии не всегда пересоздаёт сгенерированные файлы для Qt), зато потом набьёте руку и будете работать в своё удовольствие. Сам редактор Qt, лично мне, кажется несколько неудобным, по сравнению со студией. Вам же, всё таки, рекомендую попробовать и то - и то, и самому решить на чём писать лучше.

Comment: >>Еще я очень новичок<< если хотите работать в креаторе, я бы лично посоветовал скачать Qt под MinGW, он на моей практике работает без танцев с бубном

Comment: Всё,не волнуйтесь,я все сделал!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было просто поэксперементировать с компиляторами.

В настройках для каждой MSVC
надо было указать определенный компилятор

(у меня были не те).

Answer (score 0):

Установите сначала visual studio а потом Qt (под ту visual studio которая у вас стоит  ), Qt сам пропишет пути и все будет компилироваться.

Comment: Visual studio стоял до того как поставил Qt и Qt creator